# omission preposition in reported speech

Tags: ellipsis

> Sue said, ''Johnsy, Don't move and promise me not to look out of the window.''

If I change this sentence into indirect speech,

1. Sue told Johnsy not to move and **to** promise her not to look out of the window.
2. Sue told Johnsy not to move and promise her not to look out of the window.

Can I leave out ''to'' as in sentence 2? Is it incorrect omission?

Comment: You can. But it's not a preposition; it's an infinitive marker.

Comment: Eh, I don't know if I'd omit that one because not to is still felt after and, so it sounds somewhat clumsy. I'd probably put a comma before and and keep the infinitive marker, but we'd do best to wait for a more proficient speaker.